# Does getState() from redux thunk changes the actual state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm retriving a slice of the state with getState() to filter some values from the state in an event handler (before dispatching an action and updating the store with the new state slice) But changing the results from getState seems to change the actual store.

Consider the following:

```
const filterInPlace = (array, predicate) => {
    let end = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        const obj = array[i]

        if (predicate(obj)) {
            array[end++] = obj
        }
    }

    array.length = end
}
//some event handler
...
const forDeletion = new Set([...ids])
let currentState = getState().home.lists
filterInPlace(currentState, obj => !forDeletion.has(obj.rowid))
dispatch(handleSelectLists(ids)) //Leads to an action and reducer
```

Does getState() changes the store?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getState()` does not change the store, but it does return a reference to the store. Meaning when you say `let currentState = getState().home.lists`, `currentState` now points to your store. If you modify it it will change your store.

Obviously this is not what you want, so you need to make a copy.

Assuming `lists` is an array, this will do the trick.

`let currentState = [...getState().home.lists]`

Answer (score 2):

To answer your exact question, `getState()` itself does not change the store.

I think what you're trying to ask though, and what you're confused about, is that `getState()` does give you a reference to another store so modifying the *result of* `getState()` will change the original value.

via [the redux docs](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getState):

> [`getState()`] **Returns:** The current state tree of your application.

It looks like you're passing your state array into `filterInPlace` then adding items to the end of it.

If you don't want to mutate the state tree, here are some patterns you can check out: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns